# Como colocar o Action Mode na parte de cima?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Eu estou utilizando essa propriedade no manifest.xml:**

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

**1- O menu de opções aparece na parte de baixo, segue a figura abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2- E quando ocorre um clique em um item, o action mode aparece em baixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Gostaria de manter a primeira figura(menu na parte de baixo) e só mude a
>   segunda figura que ao invés do action mode aparecer em baixo, aparecer em cima igual nessa imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Possivelmente isso que eu quero não seja possível, então gostaria que
>   o action mode ficasse desse jeito:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está colocando o `showAsAction` nos seus itens de menu? Poderia incluir o xml que está inflando no Action Mode?

Comment: postei o sml dos itens

Comment: Eu acho que por não ter espaço ele está forçando a Action Bar ir para o fundo. Poderia testar colocar `showAsAction="never"` no `@+id/adicionar`, só como teste.

Comment: ta a mesma coisa... o negocio @Wakim é fazer com que o action mode fique em cima e o menu fique em baixo mas pela propriedade do manifest.xml ele sempre faz com que os dois fiquem na parte de baixo...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: @Wakim pelo que to lendo acho que não é possível fazer isso..

Comment: É... eu também acho, eu acreditei que era por falta de espaço... Mas se mesmo com espaço ele não deixou lá em cima...

Comment: @Wakim eu postei uma segunda alternativa para o action mode fique logo apos a barra do menu.. na minha ultima foto como fazer?

Comment: Não, não dá pra mudar a posição do `ActionMode`, que eu saiba... Está usando o `appcompat` correto? Já chegou a ver o `Toolbar`? Acho que usando ele, da pra fazer o que você quer.

Comment: @Wakim estou usando sim.. Toolbar não vi ainda...

Comment: Então, o `Toolbar` é um "substituto" do `ActionBar` que veio do Android Lollipop, você precisa incluir ele no seu layout usando o `appcompat v21` (pode ser no fundo) e pode remover o atributo `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`. O`ActionMode` não tem relação com ele, então ele fica no topo. Mais detalhes em: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html.

Comment: @Wakim vou dar uma olhada vlw

Comment: @Wakim ta meio complicado tenho todas as bibliotecas de suporte e ainda não to conseguindo usar toolbar.. no layout aparece um erro The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Como está seu `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Wakim nunca usei isso... pra que serve?

Comment: @Wakim agora que eu me lembrei no link que vc tinha passado tinha uma linha .. compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"